# Looking to add a done button when using UIKeyboardType.numberPad with SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, numpad

I have a TextField and using UIKeyboardType.numberPad for the keyboard entry (want integer only entries).  This keyboard type does not come with a Return/Done key.

I have struggled to find a way to add this to the keyboard.  I have done this in the past with Swift, but don’t know how to do the same with SwiftUI.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am facing same issue. Please let me know, if you find any solution for close numberPad keyboard with use of SwiftUI. (Not UIViewRepresentable with UITextField). @DanSchümacher